# Forcing Excel users to enable macros before code runs

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know, whether it is possible to force the users of my sheet, to enable macros before using.

And having my macro put on hold, before they say "OK" to enabling macros.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If there were an answer to this, the would be a hole in macro security big enough to drive a truck through.

Comment: Your macro doesn't need to be put on hold because it won't be running until the user clicks "OK" to enabling macros. There is no way with a macro to overwrite this though as that's the entire point of excel prompting the user to enable them for the workbook. If you need that level of control on the user's machine, then a Macro is not the way to go. You could use VSTO and/or Excel Interop in C#/Visual Studio though to write up a workbook that acts more like a traditional application on the users machine. Bit of a learning curve there though.

Comment: Well, my Macro from “Private sub Workbook Open()” doesn’t run upon opening, and not after allowing macros.

Comment: Is it in the `ThisWorkbook` module?  And have you include the underscore between `Workbook` and `Open` - `Workbook_Open`?

Comment: Start threatening them with violence. Just about the only way :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes it is

Comment: Is the question whether it's possible to force users to enable macros or why your `Workbook_Open` event isn't firing?

Comment: Well, would prefer to force them to accept first, but seemed as if that wasn’t possivble. So if I can get a solution for Workbook_Open, it’ll do the trick :)

Comment: I've never done it, but I believe you can digitally Sign your code /w certificates.  You'd then probably have to install the certificate on your users machine.  Not sure if you have to do something with security settings after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to have the user enable macros so that your code runs, then there is a non technical solution to it.

When opening the workbook, have all Worksheets set to `xlVeryHidden` except for one which is visible. On that visible sheet, inform the user that he must enable macros in able to use the workbook.

Once macros are enabled, have code that runs on the `Workbook_open` event and unhides the needed worksheets and hides the one worksheet that would be shown if macros are not enabled.

Comment: Creative... nice

Comment: Thanks. I have also found it to be the most reliable workaround when sending macros workbooks to customers whose systems i don't know.

Comment: Are you able to assign a macro to “whenever macro is enabled”?

Comment: @PatrickS The Workbook_Open() event is triggered immediately upon the workbook opening up. It comes before almost anything else. Infact, I'm not sure that there is anything prior, so I think it's the closest thing to what you are asking for.